# What's the correct/proper way to test if an object is a jQuery object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

I'm writing a javascript function and in "compact" javascript design fashion, the type/length of arguments changes the behaviour of the function. One possible type of the argument is a jQuery object, for which I would like very special logic.

What is the best way to test if an object is an instance of jQuery?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depends on the inner workings of jQuery, but I'd go with

```
obj instanceof jQuery
```

It's the most 'JavaScript way' of doing it. Keep in mind that it will fail when passing objects between window/frame boundaries!

Tomalak's suggestion

```
'jquery' in obj
```

should still work in this case, so you should use it if you expect to do multi-window data exchange. I wouldn't recommend it as a general solution, as just looking for a property named `'jquery'` isn't very reliable.

The `in` operator will also throw an error if `obj` is a primitive. If this behaviour is undesired, you might consider using one of these tests instead:

```
obj && obj.jquery
'jquery' in Object(obj)
```

I find the second one more appealing, but the first one will likely be faster.

Checking

```
Object(obj).hasOwnProperty('jquery')
```

will fail, as jQuery objects only inherit the property from their prototype.

I'd also discourage using the `constructor` property for type checking in JavaScript - it might work reliably for jQuery, but as `constructor` is just a property of the object pointed to by the constructor function's `prototype` property at instantiation time, there are lots of ways to mess with such tests...

---

As a side note:

jQuery itself checks for `obj && obj.jquery`. It does not use `instanceof` even once. Instead, it uses a combination of `typeof`, duck-typing and `toString.call()` for type checking, which should work where `instanceof` will fail.

Also, `hasOwnProperty()` is never used as well. I'm not sure what this says about the code quality of the jQuery library ;)

Comment: Much more detailed than my post: +1 and I recommend your post to be chosen as the answer

Comment: You got my vote for mentioning the failure of instanceof across window/frame boundaries!

Answer (score 6):

One of the following:

```
obj instanceof jQuery
obj && obj.constructor == jQuery
obj && obj.jquery
```

instanceof  [is recommended](http://markmail.org/message/62a7ximsf7txfhb3)

Comment: I would recommend against using instanceof by itself as there are [known memory leaks](http://ajaxian.com/archives/working-aroung-the-instanceof-memory-leak) when using instanceof in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of instanceof to test for jQuery objects.

```
/**
 * @see http://ajaxian.com/archives/working-aroung-the-instanceof-memory-leak
 * @return Boolean True if object is of type jQuery, false otherwise
 */
function isjQuery(obj) {
    return obj && obj.hasOwnProperty && obj instanceof jQuery;
}
```

Comment: Why should one use this instead of instanceof?